# Visual Studio 2008 shows multiple collapse solution menu items

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 Professional.  When I right-click on a solution, I get a menu that starts with Build Solution, Rebuild Solution, Clean Solution.  Then it displays about twenty items that all say "Collapse Solution" but every item, except the first "Collapse Solution," is disabled.  There are no other items in this menu.

How can I fix this menu?  I have tried repairing Visual Studio.  I have not yet reinstalled it.  I think this problem arose after I installed some free IDE components from DevExpress (along with CodeRush XPress).  I uninstalled those components and CodeRush, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step I would take is to reset the settings.

> devenv.exe /resetsettings

Comment: Awesome, JaredPar!  That fixed the problem.